# How do I allow the addition of a value to a table through a combo box in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I'm creating my fist Microsoft Access database. I need combo boxes that allow for selection from a list and also addition of values to the field that the combo box is pulling the selections from.

After a lot of googling, I found this example VBA code.

```
Private Sub cboMainCategory_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim intAnswer As Integer
    intAnswer = MsgBox("""" & NewData & """ is not an approved category. " & vbcrlf _
        & "Do you want to add it now?" _ vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Invalid Category")

    Select Case intAnswer
        Case vbYes
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tlkpCategoryNotInList (Category) "
                & _ "Select """ & NewData & """;"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            Response = acDataErrAdded
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox "Please select an item from the list.", _
                vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry"
            Response = acDataErrContinue

    End Select

    Exit_Procedure:
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Exit Sub

    Error_Handler:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ", " & Error Description
        Resume Exit_Procedure
        Resume

End Sub
```

If I use the unaltered example, it doesn't throw an error, but doesn't let me enter a new value.

I tried to alter the code to fit my database but this block throws a syntax error (I've tried to troubleshoot, but I'm new to VBA, and can't find an appropriate linter).

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Combo26_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim intAnswer As Integer
    intAnswer = MsgBox("""" & NewData & """ is not in the database yet " & vbcrlf _
        & "Do you want to add it now?" _ vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "new chemical")

    Select Case intAnswer
        Case vbYes
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO chemical_IDNotInList (chemical) "
                & _ "Select """ & NewData & """;"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            Response = acDataErrAdded
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox "Please select an item from the list.", _
                vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry"
            Response = acDataErrContinue

    End Select

    Exit_Procedure:
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Exit Sub

    Error_Handler:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ", " & Error Description
        Resume Exit_Procedure
        Resume

End Sub
```

I need a functioning combo box that both lets me select from existing values and add new ones.

Comment: A bit more info would be useful. What is the syntax error and what line does it occur on? Whats the record source for your combo box? A query? A list?

Comment: The underscore (_) in front of vbYesNo should be a comma. First version should throw same error message as well because of that typo. I wonder if the first procedure ran at all. If you didn't have combobox named cboMainCategory and associated procedure to that control, it would not.

Comment: Set breakpoint and step debug code. You will then see which line triggers error. Could also disable error handler and code execution will stop on line with issue and popup debugger window with that line highlighted.

Comment: Combo Boxes in Access do this natively with settable values on the Property Sheet. Why not just use Design View as it was intended? Especially if this is your first database... they tend to be less buggy this way.

Comment: The list is being pulled from a column in a data table. I also need new entries to add themselves to that column. Thanks for pointing out the issue with the underscore, the error is definitely later now. looks like it's line 14 column 50. If there's a way I can do this without VBA that would be fantastic. I have the "limit to list" property set to "yes"  and "on not in list" set to [event procedure]. My understanding was that you had to define that event procedure using VBA.

Comment: @Digital_ecologist - please post the ControlSource of the Combo26.

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply. Had to reconfigure my dropbox to post a link.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqrsd4vpsbj4828/Access%20error%20screenshot.png?dl=0)
There is the actual error, and here's the database file.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbcsif5zajbc2a7/catalog%20database%20restructure1.accdb?dl=0)

Comment: First link error is about wrong line continuation. Try`_ & "Select """ & NewData & """;"` .No one complaining about`DoCmd.SetWarnings False`? If`Insert`fails, you won't notice;)

Answer (score 1):

MsgBox syntax is missing a comma to separate arguments.

```
    intAnswer = MsgBox("""" & NewData & """ is not an approved category. " & vbcrlf _
        & "Do you want to add it now?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Invalid Category")
```

Comment: apologies for incorrect comment above (now deleted) - I thought you were referring to the previous underscore - doh!

Answer (score 0):

[Line continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code) is started by a blank in front of an underscore, at the end of the line, not at the beginning.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tlkpCategoryNotInList (Category) " _
                  & "Select """ & NewData & """;"
```

or

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tlkpCategoryNotInList (Category) " & _
                  "Select """ & NewData & """;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL insert command dont' look right.

Try this:

You can set the limit to yes = to yes.

The, for the no in list event, you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Combo33_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

   Dim strSql     As String
   If MsgBox(NewData & " not in list, add?", _
             vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
      strSql = "insert into tblStudents (name) values(" & NewData & ")"
      CurrentDb.Execute strSql
      Response = acDataErrAdded
   End If

End Sub
```

The insert format is as above - there is no select command.

Note I used a table name of Students, and field name of Sname. So, just
change the table name, and the field to whatever you used.

Comment: thanks! This was very helpful. I'm now getting the right message in the dialog box, but then it's throwing additional errors. going to post 3 links, first the dialogue then the code error than the revised VBA.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kuw85g7mdjoubgr/new%20error%20message.pdf?dl=0)
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tmskp3vvbpfc3z8/new%20debug%20output.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: sorry for the follow-up, last link disappeared.
[link](https://pastebin.com/Azew47ub)